# Smallest singular value of product of 2 random matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, random-matrices, singular-values

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$ be two random matrices (each element is drawn iid from a normal distribution).
Also $n<m<k$.

Let $\sigma_{min}(A)$ be the smallest singular value of $A$.

Is the following true (with prob. 1)?
$$\sigma_{min}(AB) \geq \sigma_{min}(A)\sigma_{min}(B)$$
If so, why?
If not, can we say something about the probability of that?

I ran a lot of simulations, and in all of them I got that the statement is true, but then again, it is only simulations.

Also, I can prove it using square matrices (using the fact that $\sigma_{min}(A)=(\sigma_{max}(A^{-1}))^{-1}$ and $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Both sides of the inequality are zero if $B$ has deficient column rank. When $B$ has full column rank (so that $Bx\ne0$ when $x\ne0$),
$$
\sigma_\min(AB)
=\min_{x\ne0}\frac{\|ABx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}
=\min_{x\ne0}\frac{\|ABx\|_2}{\|Bx\|_2}\frac{\|Bx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}
\ge\min_{y\ne0}\frac{\|Ay\|_2}{\|y\|_2}\min_{x\ne0}\frac{\|Bx\|_2}{\|x\|_2}
=\sigma_\min(A)\sigma_\min(B).
$$

Comment: So elegant and simple! Thanks!

Comment: @user1551 Do I understand correctly that this holds for all $A$ and $B$, i.e. this statement need not be a probabilistic one?

Comment: @gen Yes, it holds for all $A$ and $B$.

Comment: If $A$ is short and wide, is $\min_{y\neq 0} \|Ay\|_2/\|y\|_2 = \sigma_{\min}(A)$? For instance $A=[1,0]$ then $y=[0,1]$ gives zero but the min singular value is 1.

Comment: @tch In my answer I assumed that $A$ and $B$ are tall. The OP had changed the setting from $n>m>k$ ($A$ and $B$ are tall) to $n<m<k$ ($A$ and $B$ are fat). I think I didn't notice this change while I was typing this answer. Anyway, since a matrix has the same singular values as its transpose, a similar reasoning applies (just consider $x^TAB$ and $x^TA$ instead of $ABx$ and $Bx$) and the conclusion still holds.